# How to register a custom binding extension in code for a self hosted WCF service?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0, wcf-binding, pollingduplexhttpbinding

I need a suggestion to register my custom binding extension for my Silverlight duplex commnication (to use PollingDuplexHttpBinding) for my self hosted WCF service.

Below are the binding details, which I got from [this msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28VS.95%29.aspx).

```xml
<!-- Register the binding extension from the SDK. -->
   <extensions>
      <bindingExtensions>
        <add name="pollingDuplexHttpBinding"
            type="System.ServiceModel.Configuration.PollingDuplexHttpBindingCollectionElement,System.ServiceModel.PollingDuplex, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </bindingExtensions>
   </extensions>
```

I need add the above xml code through the codebehind into my custom binding.

Comment: I need add the above xml code through the codebehind into my custom binding

Comment: If you're adding it via code, just create a custom binding with the PollingDuplexBindingElement. Or add the `PollingDuplexHttpBinding` directly (don't use a custom binding).

Comment: Thank you carlosfigueira...I found the solution.